# MS ACCESS Compact and Repair using Python is giving the error file can not open exclusively

Tags: python, ms-access

I tried the following script but that is giving me the error

> IDispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(IDispatch, None, clsctx, pythoncom.IID_IDispatch)
>   pywintypes.com_error: (-2146959355, 'Server execution failed', None, None)

```
objAccess = win32com.client.Dispatch("Access.application")
objAccess.compactRepair(srcDB, destDB)
```

Can anybody help me with this please.

Comment: Take care that there really is no process left using this file. Maybe an orphaned process from testings before? Or a Microsoft Access Application without UI caused by automation?

Comment: Trying to automate compact and repair a MS Access db file

Answer (score 0):

To open the database in exclusive mode, you need to change `"/"` to "backslash" `\` in the path:

```
path_bdd_access = path_bdd_access.replace('/', chr(92))
```